# Window function to select the most recent non-null value in Postgresql doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I have a simple dataset like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (ts timestamp, email varchar, title varchar, hobby varchar);

insert into test values
('2017-01-01', 'me@me.com', 'blah', null),
('2017-01-02', 'me@me.com', null, 'expected hobby'),
('2017-01-03', 'me@me.com', 'expected title', null),
('2017-01-04', 'me@me.com', null, null);
```

And I'd like to select the most recent non-null value of title and hobby per email, using a window function. These are 'expected title' and 'expected hobby'. I'm trying this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    email,
    first_value(title) OVER (partition by email order by ts desc nulls last),
    first_value(hobby) OVER (partition by email order by ts desc nulls last)
from test
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Here's a sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6d681/2

Any idea why?

Comment: I may have solved this with: `first_value(title) OVER (partition by email order by case when title is not null then ts end desc nulls last),`

Comment: It seems to work. You should put it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it using a case statement to eliminate the nulls:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    email,
    first_value(title) OVER (partition by email order by case when title is not null then ts end desc nulls last),
    first_value(hobby) OVER (partition by email order by case when hobby is not null then ts end desc nulls last),
from test
```

Answer (score 1):

your order does not work as excpected

```
 order by ts desc nulls last
```

because ts has no nulls,
something like that should also work (as your solution)

```
SELECT distinct 
    email,
    first_value(title) OVER (partition by email order by (ts || title) desc nulls last ROWS  BETWEEN  UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) as title,
    first_value(hobby) OVER (partition by email order by (ts || hobby) desc nulls last ROWS  BETWEEN  UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) as hobby
from test
```

a concat with null results in null, so ts || null results in null